# Mi botón dentro de una función no responde a la condición IF

Tags: javascript, videojs

No puedo hacer que al hacer clic en un botón, se pueda activar una función Javascript.

Estoy usando una librería Javascript llamada VideoJS y la utilizo junto la extensión "Youtube extension" (de la misma librería) que me permite interactuar con videos, y junto con la extensión puedo interactuar con videos de Youtube. El video funciona y el reproductor también, sólo que debido a que algunos navegadores por defecto tienen la "obligación" de desactivar el sonido de los videos (por razones de experiencia de usuario), debo de crear un botón y una función para volver a reactivar el sonido.

Anexo Codepen: https://codepen.io/eduardonwa/pen/KKaBgdw

1. Una vez creada la etiqueta de `<video>`, agrego un botón en mi HTML, y le asgino la clase de `.mute-control` este será el que active el sonido
2. Desde JavaScript inició la función de `ready` para poder cargar el reproductor en la página (estamos utilizando esta función para controlar el video con VideoJS, no queremos utilizar las propiedades HTML)
3. Le asigno la propiedad de autoplay al reproducto y le asigno el parámetro "muted" marcado por la librería ya que quiero que el video se auto reproduzca recién la página sea cargada.
4. Ahora el navegador es capaz de auto reproducir el video pero sin sonido como quedo establecido
5. Necesito agregar un If ligando mi botón con un `addEventListener` y mediante una función activar el sonido

Esta son mis funciones:

```
<script>  
  var player = videojs('vid1', { 
    "techOrder": ["youtube"], 
    "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", 
    "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n23qfZawlw"}], 
    "aspectRatio": '13:5',
    "poster": '/img/thpsvido-logo.svg'
  }) // propiedades para la extension Youtube
  
  // Empieza la función VideoJs
  player.ready(function() {
    player.autoplay('muted');
    myPlayer = this;
    if(myPlayer.muted()) {
      const myButton = document.getElementsByClassName('mute-control');
      myButton.addEventListener('click', function() { myPlayer.muted(false); })
    }
  });
</script>
```

El video debería de auto-reproducirse y al hacer clic en el botón que le asigné la clase de `.mute-control` el sonido debería de activarse, y debería quitarse el sonido si le vuelvo a dar clic, ya que así es la función por default en la librería. Cuando presiono sobre el botón no obtengo audio.

Estructura HTML completa

```
<div>    

  <div>
    <h1>Título del video</h1>

    <a href="url/del/video.mp4">
      Botón "Play Now"
    </a>

    <span class="mute-control>
         Activar Sonido
    </span>

  </div>

  <video
    id="vid1"
    class="video-js"
  >
  </video>

</div> <!-- Fin de HTML -->

<!-- videojs -->
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset ('/js/Youtube.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>  
  var player = videojs('vid1', { 
    "techOrder": ["youtube"], 
    "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", 
    "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n23qfZawlw"}], 
    "aspectRatio": '13:5',
    "poster": '/img/thpsvido-logo.svg'
  })
  
  player.ready(function() {

    player.autoplay('muted');

    myPlayer = this;
    if(myPlayer.muted()) {
      const myButton = document.getElementsByClassName('mute-control');
      myButton.addEventListener('click', function() { myPlayer.muted(false); })
    }

  });
</script>
```

La consola no me tira ningún error ó advertencias.

Como dije, estoy utilizando VideoJS versión 7.10.2, junto con la extensión Youtube es un proyecto Laravel 8 en Windows 10.

Comment: El problema es que `.getElementsByClassName()` devuelve una colección HTML y no puedes asignar eventos, deberías recorrer cada nodo. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el HTML y saber si puedes obtener el botón solo con `.querySelector('.mute-control')` o se requiere algo diferente.

Comment: Ya quedo la edición @Triby

Comment: Parece que cambiando la forma de obtener el botón podría solucionar el problema: `const myButton = document.querySelector('.mute-control');`

Comment: ¿Te funciona de esa manera? Eso fue algo que también intente pero seguía teniendo el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dije en comentarios, [.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassname) devuelve una [colección HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) y no puedes acceder directamente a sus elementos, debes especificar un índice. Por ejemplo:

```
// Agrega [0] al final para obtener el primer (¿único?) elemento
const myButton = document.getElementsByClassName('mute-control')[0];
```

Para mí, resulta más simple el uso de [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) porque es más corto y devuelve solo un elemento:

```
// Solo agrega un punto al nombre de clase
const myButton = document.querySelector('.mute-control');
```

En el fragmento de código no se termina de cargar el video, por lo que no se ejecuta la función `player.ready()`. Para probar, puse hasta abajo el *span* que activa el sonido y dupliqué el código al final del *Javascript*.

```js
  var player = videojs('vid1', { 
    "techOrder": ["youtube"], 
    "sources": [
      {
        "type": "video/youtube", 
        "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYpOsgBdN6k"
      }
    ], 
    "aspectRatio": '13:5',
    "poster": '/img/thpsvido-logo.svg'
  });
  
  player.ready(function() {
    player.autoplay('muted');
    console.log(mPlayer.muted());

    myPlayer = this;
    if(myPlayer.muted()) {
      const myButton = document.querySelector('.mute-control');
      myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
          myPlayer.muted(false);
          console.log(mPlayer.muted());
      });
    }
  });

// Para probar que funciona
const myButton = document.querySelector('.mute-control');
myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('¡Clic!');
});
```

```html
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/videojs-youtube@2.6.1/dist/Youtube.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <h1>Título del video</h1>

    <a href="url/del/video.mp4">
      Botón "Play Now"
    </a>

  </div>

  <video
    id="vid1"
    class="video-js"
  >
  </video>

</div>
<span class="mute-control">Activar Sonido</span>
```